# suma dinámica de todos los valores de una columna - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

**Buen día, tengo un tabla "https://material-table-core.com/demos/Summaryrow/basic" en reactjs y necesito que todos los valores de la columna de valor_t2 se sumen y me muestre el resultado al final de la tabla.
ya la tabla esta sumando los valores de la columna valor_t2 pero necesito que al interactuar con el search predeterminado de la tabla también el valor final tambien se actualice. cuando la tabla carga aparece la suma sin problemas pero cuando interactuó con el buscador que aparece por defecto de la tabla el valor de la suma no cambia y necesito que sea dinamia y sume únicamente lo que hay en la tabla.**

//codigo
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-rumple-x6fzwi?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MaterialTable from "@material-table/core";

import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const peticionGet = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(
        `https://parqueoenvia.co/apiParqueoenvia/operadores/arqueo_cargar.php?id_operador=59`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      peticionGet();
    }, 3000);

    return () => setInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  const columnas = [
    {
      title: "FECHA",
      field: "fecha_hora"
    },

    {
      title: "age",
      field: "valor_t2"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div id="content" className="app-content">
      <div className="panel-body">
        {data.length === 0 ? (
          <p>cargando...</p>
        ) : (
          <MaterialTable
            columns={columnas}
            data={data}
            // title={ }
            // backIconButtonText='Página anterior'
            pagination
            fixedHeader
            renderSummaryRow={({ column, data }) =>
              column.field === "valor_t2"
                ? {
                    value: data.reduce(
                      (agg, row) => agg + Number(row.valor_t2),
                      0
                    ),
                    style: { background: "red" }
                  }
                : undefined
            }
            actions={[]}
            options={{
              actionsColumnIndex: -1,
              actionsCellStyle: {},

              body: {
                emptyDataSourceMessage: "No hay registros que mostrar"
              }
            }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: El componente es el renderSummaryRow Pero esta dentro de materialTable , como podría hacer el botón para que funcione con un botón

Comment: tu código contiene varios errores, faltan llaves varias llaves de cierre, por favor edita tu código y sube nuevamente para que sea mas fácil replicar tu ejemplo. Otra cosa es que `renderSummaryRow` no parece una propiedad existente de `material-table` por lo que no estoy seguro si funciona, de momento esa propiedad si te muestra información ?

Comment: La propiedad renderSummaryRow funciona esta es la documentación https://material-table-core.com/demos/Summaryrow/basic, el inconveniente que tengo es solo cuando se ejecuta ya que no alcanza a obtener los valores de mi base de datos y queda en 0

Comment: te envio el link en codebox https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-rumple-x6fzwi?file=/src/App.js:0-1837

Comment: por favor [edit]  y coloca el código, el enlace es muy útil y ayuda mucho para poder replicar el problema. _pero también incluye el mismo código en tu pregunta. No todos pueden acceder a sitios externos, y los enlaces se pueden quebrar con el tiempo._ por lo menos lo suficiente para replicar o ver el problema. Puedes revisar [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problema 1:

**cargar el resultado de la suma de los datos en la tabla**

Recomiendo que para cargar tu información y evitar solicitudes innecesarias a tu endpoind, recomiendo que uses `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  peticionGet();
}, []);
```

Párese ser un problema directo con la `renderSummaryRow`. Ya que los datos supuestamente cargados no los reconoce,  por lo que una solución rápida sería esperar a que termine la solicitud de tu endpoint, una ves cargado los datos ahora si solicitamos mostrar tu tabla ya con datos.

esto lo podemos hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
{
  data.length === 0 
    ? <p>cargando...</p>
    : <MaterialTable 
    ...
    />
}
```

---

## Problema 2:

**Obtener el resultado de la suma de los datos en la tabla al buscar**

A falta de información de lo que ya se a intentado, algún ejemplo mínimo de lo que se quiere lograr o incluso saber si da algún error especifico.
**Esto lo resuelvo a como se me hace la forma mas rápida, por las limitaciones de `@material-table`**

Ya que `renderSummaryRow` no proporciona la información correcta de los datos que se están mostrando en la tabla usaremos un `useState` extra.

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
```

Recomiendo que su primera carga se realicé al obtener la información, que sería en `peticionGet`, ejemplo:

```
const peticionGet = async () => {
  await axios
    .get(
      `https://parqueoenvia.co/apiParqueoenvia/operadores/arqueo_cargar.php?id_operador=59`
    )
    .then((response) => {
      const encontrado = response.data.map(value =>parseFloat(value.valor_t2));
      if (encontrado.length > 0) {
        const totalEncontrado = encontrado.reduce((prev,current)=>prev+current);
        setTotal(totalEncontrado);
      }
      setData(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

creamos nuestro método que buscara la información que posiblemente este en la tabla y se realizara nuevamente el calculo para mostrar.

```
const totalOnSearch = (text) => {
  if (text.length === 0) {
    const encontrado = data.map(value =>parseFloat(value.valor_t2));
    if (encontrado.length > 0) {
      const totalEncontrado = encontrado.reduce((prev,current)=>prev+current);
      setTotal(totalEncontrado);
    }
    return;
  }

  const encontrado = data.filter(value => value.fecha_hora.includes(text)).map(value =>parseFloat(value.valor_t2));
  if (encontrado.length > 0) {
    const totalEncontrado = encontrado.reduce((prev,current)=>prev+current);
    setTotal(totalEncontrado);
  }else{
    setTotal(0);
  }
};
```

como no es posible cambiar los datos del todo en `@material-table`. El total se mostrara en fuera de la tabla o donde sea mas cómodo, en este caso con un `h2`.

Quedando el código de la siguiente manera

```
return (
  <div id="content" className="app-content">
    <div className="panel-body">
      {data.length === 0 ? (
        <p>cargando...</p>
      ) : (
        <MaterialTable
          onSearchChange={totalOnSearch}
          ...
      )}
    </div>
    <h2>total: {total}</h2>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: La solución esta casi completa solo hay un inconveniente el valor me lo muestra pero si filtro algo puntual el search de la tabla el valor no esta cambiando.

Comment: @Giovanny Eso quedaría para otra pregunta, en la cual especifiques todo el problema, ya que se requiere de mas información, del como funciona tu método de búsqueda o como lo usas. De igual manera cambia el titulo de tu pregunta, ya que la respuesta y o pregunta no se relaciona con un button para sumar.

Comment: el search que aparece predeterminado de de la tabla, donde un filtra datos ya cargados.

Comment: @Giovanny Edite mi respuesta para ayudarte con tu problema de búsqueda. La próxima ves considera agregar toda la información posible sobre tu problema, al igual todo lo que ya has intentado y errores, esto ayudara a que recibas respuesta mas rápido o información. Si mi respuesta te ayudo recuerda aceptar la respuesta como correcta.

Comment: Richard, cuando agrego "const totalOnSearch = (text: string) => { " no me reconoce text:String dice que es de typescript y yo estoy manejando .js, y en la petición get no esta la ruta donde llamo a mi base de datos.

Comment: @Giovanny con eso debería estar funcionando, en la petición get, quise evitar repetir el código, pero de igual manera lo agregue para que sea un poco mas clara la respuesta.

Comment: Richard, ya integre el código pero me aparece es un numero largo cuando escribo algo en el search https://codesandbox.io/s/black-darkness-bjk0jo?file=/src/App.js , la variable total la puede ver encima del search.

Comment: @Giovanny eso es por que tu columna son `string` solo tienes que hacer la conversión a float o int, lo que que quieras, igual edite mi pregunta hice el cambio y ya puedes probarlo

Comment: como hago para agregar otro filter((value) => value.expDate.includes(text) no encuentro  como

Comment: richard, listo muchas gracias ya pude agregar otro filter, tengo otra pregunta con el mismo codigo , estoy intentando dejar la tabla en el idioma español pero no he logrado hacerlo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/550554/mostrar-tabla-en-idioma-espa%c3%b1ol-reactjs