# mostrar tabla en idioma español - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

**buen dia, tengo una tabla con "https://material-table-core.com", pero no he podido dejar que la tabla aparezca en español, me parece por default en ingles, he intentado agregar "localization" pero no me esta funcionando en material-table/core, e buscado pero no he podido dejar que aparezca en español, envio el código que tengo, tambien la localization aunque esta comentada pro que produce un error, he intendo pero no he logrado dejar que la tabla aparezca en español el search y todas las opciones que tiene:**

//code
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-platform-4in3zg?file=/src/App.js

//code

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MaterialTable from "@material-table/core";

import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  //const baseUrlAd = `https://parqueoenvia.co/apiParqueoenvia/operadores/arqueo_cargar.php?id_operador=${global.id}`;
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const peticionGet = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(
        `https://parqueoenvia.co/apiParqueoenvia/operadores/arqueo_cargar.php?id_operador=59`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      peticionGet();
    }, 3000);

    return () => setInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  const toMoney = (value) => {
    const money = Number(value);

    if (isNaN(money)) {
      return value;
    }

    return new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "USD"
    }).format(money);
  };

  const columnas = [
    {
      title: "FECHA",
      field: "fecha_hora"
    },

    {
      title: "valor_t2",
      field: "valor_t2",
      render: (field) => toMoney(field.valor_t2)
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div id="content" className="app-content">
      <div className="panel-body">
        {data.length === 0 ? (
          <p>cargando...</p>
        ) : (
          <MaterialTable
            columns={columnas}
            data={data}
            // title={ }
            //backIconButtonText="Página anterior"
            pagination
            fixedHeader
            renderSummaryRow={({ column, data }) =>
              column.field === "valor_t2"
                ? {
                    value: toMoney(
                      data.reduce((agg, row) => agg + Number(row.valor_t2), 0)
                    ),
                    style: { background: "red" }
                  }
                : undefined
            }
            actions={[]}
            options={{
              actionsColumnIndex: -1,
              actionsCellStyle: {},

              body: {
                emptyDataSourceMessage: "No hay registros que mostrar"
              }
            }}

            /*localization={{
    header:{
    actions: 'ACCIONES'
    
  },
  body:{ 
    emptyDataSourceMessage:'No hay registros que mostrar',
    
   },

 

   pagination: {
     firstAriaLabel: 'Primera página',
     firstTooltip: 'Primera página',
     labelDisplayedRows: '{from}-{to} de {count}',
     labelRowsPerPage: 'Filas por página:',
     labelRowsSelect: 'filas',
     lastAriaLabel: 'Ultima página',
     lastTooltip: 'Ultima página',
     nextAriaLabel: 'Pagina siguiente',
     nextTooltip: 'Pagina siguiente',
     previousAriaLabel: 'Pagina anterior',
     previousTooltip: 'Pagina anterior',
   },
   toolbar: {
     searchPlaceholder: 'Buscar',
     searchTooltip: 'Buscar',
     showColumnsAriaLabel: 'Mostrar columnas',
     showColumnsTitle: 'Mostrar columnas',
   },

   
}}*/
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

la única solución que encontré fue ir directamente  al modulo node_modules@material-table\core\dist\defaults\props.localization y cambiar el idioma manualmente, por que en la documentación "https://material-table-core.com" todavía no aparece implementada, si alguien tiene una mejor solución quedo pendiente.